# PostgreSQL transaction lock

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I'm using pg, pg-native for my project, I use transaction something like below code, I'm not familiar with database,
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Transactions
1. Does this lock table or only lock the row?
2. The lock does it means diable `Create`, `Update`, `Delete` in `CRUD`. but still can be `Read`? if so, the data be select, is it the data before this change (before `BEGIN`)?

"pg": "^4.5.1",
"pg-native": "^1.10.0",

```
var pg = require('pg').native;
...

var rollback = function(dbClient, response) {
  dbClient.query('ROLLBACK', function() {
    dbClient.end();
    // reject(response);
  });
};

dbClient.query('BEGIN', function(error, result) {
  ...

dbClient.query('COMMIT', dbClient.end.bind(dbClient));
  ...
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read how `BEGIN` works in the official documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-begin.html, plus here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-transaction.html

Comment: @vitaly-t thanks for reply, I been there before, but I can't find answer..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) for the complete picture. It is worth the effort.

PostgreSQL has different levels of locking: table locks and row locks (I won't go into advisory loks).

Table locks can be taken explicitly with the `LOCK` command, but that's something you don't do normally. The normal case are implicit table locks that are taken when you access a table – for example, when you read or write data in a table, a lock will be taken that prevents concurrent users from `ALTER` or `DROP` on the table.

Row locks are taken by DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) as well as by `SELECT ... FOR SHARE/UPDATE`. They prevent concurrent modification of the locked row.

All locks are released at the end of a transaction. If you didn't explicitly start a transaction, each statement runs in its own transaction, and locks won't outlast the duration of the single statement. If you start a transaction explicitly with `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`, it lasts until you `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

One important design concept of PostgreSQL (and any other database that uses *multiversion concurrency control*) is that readers never block writers and vice versa. This is facilitated by keeping old versions of the data around, and readers are served with data that are valid at their *snapshot* (roughly, the consistent view of the database valid at statement or transaction start).
These old rows are eventually cleaned up by the *autovacuum* background process.